# Meteor Package Management Conflict

Tags: meteor, meteorite, iron-router

I am getting this error when I try to run my meteor app:

```
Problem installing iron-router
  ✘ [0.6.4] conflicts with [tag: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router.git#v0.6.4]
Can't resolve dependencies! Use --force if you don't mind mrt taking a wild guess and running your app anyway.
```

This only started happening recently when I ran `mrt add {{package_name}}` and then mrt took it upon itself to upgrade all of the packages. I've deliberately not upgraded this app to Meteor's .8 release yet, so that broke everything because most of the packages had upgraded and were not backwards compatible.

To fix this, I decided to change the top level smart.json to reflect the package state before I upgraded. I then rm -rf'ed iron-router as well as accounts-entry (depends on iron-router), ran mrt remove on them, and then try adding them back again. This works on the package level - it yields the right ones - but I still get that error above and my app does not run.

```
{
  "packages": {
    "iron-router": {
      "git": "https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router.git",
      "tag": "v0.6.4"
    },
    "accounts-entry": {
      "git": "https://github.com/BeDifferential/accounts-entry.git",
      "tag": "v0.6.2"
    },
    "accounts-t9n": {
      "git": "https://github.com/softwarerero/meteor-accounts-t9n.git",
      "tag": "v0.0.2"
    },
    "typeahead": {},
    "roles": {
      "git": "https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles.git",
      "tag": "v1.2.6"
    },
    "bootstrap-themes": {},
    "font-awesome": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a mess inside `~/.meteorite` directory. Have you tried deleting it and instaling eveything from scratch? (i.e. `mrt install`)

Comment: no, i haven't. i'll try that now.

Comment: when i did that, i got another error saying: ✘ [0.6.4] conflicts with [tag: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router.git#v0.6.4]

Comment: What exact version of meteor you're using? (i.e. what is inside the `./meteor/release` file) You can also try checking out the specific tag manually and put a symlink inside `packages` directory (that's more or less what `meteorite` does). Run `meteor` (you can ignore `mrt`) and see what happens.

Comment: I'm on 0.7.2. Before I uninstalled the entire .meteorite directory, the app would start but nothing would work because all kinds of errors would ensue such as "Meteor not found", "Template not found", "Router not found", etc. I thought this was strange, but really just a consequence of something else that's broken.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by a convoluted process of deleting the ~/.meteorite directory, then re-installing everything in a particular order.